# three.js - Imported object, but no material to be seen

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I made an object in blender and I exported using gltf format. The mesh loads nicely, but it doesn't load the material that I made for the object. The 2 images shows a comparison between the blender file and how it got loaded onto the scene.

[Object in blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkQbz.jpg)

[Obejct in threejs scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INlXB.jpg)

Here's the code that I used:

```
var Scene = new THREE.Scene();

var cameraZoom = 40;
var Camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / - cameraZoom, window.innerWidth / cameraZoom, window.innerHeight / cameraZoom, window.innerHeight / - cameraZoom, 0.1, 1000);
Camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);

var Renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
Renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(Renderer.domElement);

//GLTF loader set up, for loading our object
var GLTFLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
var CastleWall; //A reference to the mesh in blender

function Initialise() {
    GLTFLoader.load('Models/CastleWall.glb', function (GLTF)
    {
        Scene.add(GLTF.scene);
        CastleWall = GLTF.scene.getObjectByName('CastleWall');
        CastleWall.position.set(-16, 9, 0);
        CastleWall.rotation.set(0, 1.5708, 0);
    });
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1, 50);
    light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
    Scene.add(light);
};

function Update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(Update);
    Renderer.render(Scene, Camera);
};

Initialise();
Update();
```

I've checked the console but it said that the material I have named has been exported. Also for some reason, it worked with image textures and basic colours.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[Shaders Graph for my material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pRbp.jpg)

Comment: Make sure your Blender materials are set up for glTF export as documented here:  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/import_export/io_scene_gltf2.html#exported-materials

Comment: @emackey I've read through the documentation and tried some solution but the exporter still ignores my material. If you wish to look at my shaders graph then, it is at the bottom of my post

Comment: Yeah, you've got Color Ramp nodes, Add/Multiply nodes, fractal noise, the works in there.  glTF doesn't have nodes, just image textures.  You don't want some mobile phone attempting to do all that math per-pixel on a battery-operated GPU.  Use the Blender Cycles "Bake" panel to bake complex materials to images (base color, metal, roughness, and normal image maps) that can be used in glTF.

Comment: I never heard of baking materials into images. I tried it out and it seemed to do the trick with exporting the material that I wanted. Thanks dude